# Two-factor authentication out of the box

Tags: two-factor-authentication

We want to enable two-factor authentication via email when user logs in to his account. The Lightning platform now sends the verification code to the user's email only for the first time but our requirement is to send this code on every login. I found a solution using Login flow but it requires coding.

Is there a solution  that does not require coding or something that Salesforce provides out of the box.

Comment: This is available [out of the box](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_require_two-factor_authentication.htm&type=5)

Comment: Yes identigral , this is fine if we are using salesforce Authenticator app or any other Authenticator apps. but we don't need to use any app , we need to use user's email to get the verification code.

Comment: The best you can do out of the box for authentication via email is a so-called [passwordless login](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_identity_login_discovery_create_discovery.htm&type=5). That is 1 factor, not 2 factors and it only works for communities.

Comment: Thank you identigral ,our requirement is for our internal staff because they are working now from their home and need more secure method to access their accounts.1 factor is not acceptable.

Comment: In that case your only  option is to use login flow + code.

Comment: Yes , also there is ready ummanaged package from salesforce on this link :
https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04to0000000WA6J
 i will try to install it.Thank you.